# What's the difference in meaning between "expect someone to do something" and "be expecting someone to do something"?

Tags: difference, present-continuous, present-simple

Can you please tell me what's the difference in meaning between *expect someone to do something* and *be expecting someone to do something*? For example:

> The boss **expects** me to finish the project by Friday.
>
> The boss **is expecting** me to finish the project by Friday.
>
> I don't **expect** you to return the book right away.
>
> I'**m** not **expecting** you to return the book right away.

I hear both used but can't figure out the slight difference in meaning and the contexts where one is used rather than the other. Unfortunately the grammar books I have don't answer the question.

Comment: Present simple and present continuous are both used to express the future. I (don't) leave for Paris on Wednesday.  I'm (not) leaving for Paris on Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is  slight.  When you say "is expecting" there is a sense of the ongoing nature of the expectation.  When you say "expects" you are referring to an expectation in the present moment.  But a native speaker, at least of American English, is not likely to be conscious of this difference.  For practical purposes, both forms are equivalent.

Comment: As a BrE speaker, if the boss expects me to do sth they would always expect that, whereas 'is expecting' is in the present moment, or quite soon.

Comment: To me (also BrE), _expect someone to do something_ can have overtones of _requiring_ them to do it (you will be in trouble if you don't finish the project by Friday), while _be expecting someone to do something_ sounds more relaxed, like a prediction (the project shouldn't take more than a few days).